# session_start() is not success when use multi byte into the session in cakephp3

Tags: php, cakephp, multibyte, cakephp-3.1

Recently I started to use cakephp3.1 and I get the error that bellow.

> Warning (2): session_start(): Trying to destroy uninitialized session [CORE/src/Network/Session.php, line 324]
>
> Warning (2): session_start() [function.session-start]: Failed to decode session object. Session has been destroyed [CORE/src/Network/Session.php, line 324]
>
> Warning (2): session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/www/service/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Error/Debugger.php:742) [CORE/src/Network/Session.php, line 324]

When I set multi byte word into the session such as login user's name is Japanese or something multi byte word set to flash, it's happen.

So I assumed I did't installed mbstring extension. However there's already installed.

Comment: `Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/www/service/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Error/Debugger.php:742)` - what is the output - it's an error message you need to read and fix.

Answer (score 1):

This generally happens due to the session storage not being able to handle multibyte characters. If the storage is a mysql database then setting the

**Character Set** to **utf8**

**Collation** to **utf8_general_ci**

for the **table** and **the field holding the session data** solves these problems.

Answer (score 0):

Use [base64_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php)
This may be useful for you using multi byte string
I'm using it for Hindi language.

Answer (score 0):

Set database encoding to utf8_general_ci